# Problems with a Python if-else statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am doing an assignment for an IT class. Very basic Python projects. I have no experience with it but am able to grasp what is going on most of the time. This project involves making choices involving random integer selections. I can get the options to work the way I want in the if-else format but the else command isn't responding the way I want. The options all load properly but if the choice is 1-3 for some reason the program then prints the "else" statement after printing the "if" statements. This doesn't happen if they choose option 4 or pick an invalid number(the reason for the else statement).

I didn't have this issue in the previous section of the program. I must have missed something, but I can't tell what it is. I should reiterate I am very much a beginner at this and am basically copy-pasting code as the assignment instructed, and then editing it to suit my needs.

```
interactions = ["Back Away Slowly","Point Towards the Chamber","Attack","Try To Communicate",]
import random
badchoice = random.randint(1,3)
loop = 1

while loop == 1:
    choice=menu(interactions, "How do you decide to interact?")
    print("")

    if choice == 1:
        print("You start to slowly back away from the man.")
        print("You worry you are giving off the wrong attitude.")
        print("")

        if choice == badchoice:
            loop=0
            print("The stranger was already weary of your presence.")
            print(interactions[choice-1], "was not the correct decision.")
            print("He calls for help. Villagers and guards immediately surround you.")
            print("You are thrown back into the chamber. Hitting your head, and getting knocked unconscious in the process.")
            print("You are back where you started and the items have been removed.")
            print("There is no escape.")
            print("Lamashtu's Curse can not be broken.")
            print("Game Over.")

        else:
            print("The stranger looks at you in confusion.")
            print("")

# Choices 2 and 3 go here. Same code. Seemed redundant to post all of it.    


    if choice == 4:
        loop=0
        print("The stranger is weary of your presence, and can not understand you.")
        print("You can see in his eyes that he wants to help,")
        print("and he escorts you back to his home for the time being.")
        print("He offers you some much needed food and water.")
        print("You are no closer to understanding what curse brought you here.")
        print("Perhaps tomorrow you will have more time to inspect your surroundings.")
        print("In time you may be able to communicate enough  with your host to explain your dilemma,")
        print("but for now you are trapped 6000 years in the past with no other options.")
        print("At least you've made it out alive thus far......")
        print("To be continued...")

    else:
        print("Please choose a number between 1 and 4.")
```

Comment: Post your code here, don't link to a separate place.

Comment: Sorry. Had issues formatting it at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` only applies to the most recent `if` at the same level, ie the one for number 4. The other three `if` statements are all independent. So after checking each of those, it then goes to check if the choice is 4, and runs the else if it isn't.

You need to make these all part of the same statement, which you do by using `elif` for every if after the first. Like this:

```
if choice == 1:
    ...
elif choice == 2:
    ...
elif choice == 3:
    ...
elif choice == 4:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have been able to fix that on my own but I'm basically brand new at this. So I'm assuming any if-else with more than two options require the elif statement?

Comment: Yes. The key to understand is that `if` will always start a new independent condition

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect.  Your final `if` statement directs choice `4` to it's `True` branch, and everything else to the `False` branch.  Python does exactly what you told it to do.  There is no logical reference to the previous blocks.

The logic you need is

```
if choice == 1:
    ...
elif choice == 2:
    ...
elif choice == 3:
    ...
elif choice == 4:
    ...
else:
    print("Please choose a number between 1 and 4.")
```

Comment: I feel like I should have been able to pick up on that on my own. Like I said, I've only been doing this for a few hours and had problems trying to use elifs already. I thought this was a way around it. Thank you, kind sir.